# what is a subexpression of an initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, language-lawyer, exception-specification

```cpp
struct B {
  B() throw();
  B(const B&) = default;        // implicit exception specification is noexcept(true)
  B(B&&, int = (throw Y(), 0)) noexcept;
  ~B() noexcept(false);
};
int n = 7;
struct D : public A, public B {
    int * p = new int[n];
    // D​::​D() potentially-throwing, as the new operator may throw bad_­alloc or bad_­array_­new_­length
    // D​::​D(const D&) non-throwing
    // D​::​D(D&&) potentially-throwing, as the default argument for B's constructor may throw
    // D​::​ D() potentially-throwing
};
```

Consider the above code which is cited from [except.spec#11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/except.spec#11). I have no doubt to the exception specification of all constructors of D except for `D::D(D&&)`, which obeys the following rule:

> An implicitly-declared constructor for a class X, or a constructor without a noexcept-specifier that is defaulted on its first declaration, has a potentially-throwing exception specification if and only if any of the following constructs is potentially-throwing:
>
> - a constructor selected by overload resolution in the implicit definition of the constructor for class X to initialize a potentially constructed subobject, or
> - **a subexpression of such an initialization**, such as a default argument expression, or,
> - for a default constructor, a default member initializer.

Obviously, The rule to make `D​::​D(D&&)` have a potentially-throwing exception specification is neither the first bullet nor the third bullet. For the first rule, the selected constructor to initialize base subobject of type `B` is  `B(B&&, int = (throw Y(), 0)) noexcept`, which is declared to have a non-throwing exception specification. The third rule is for default constructor. So only the second rule applies to this case.

However, `D​::​D(D&&)` shouldn't have a potentially-throwing exception specification except that the expression `throw Y()` is considered as a subexpression of `D​::​D(D&&)`.

The rule which define the immediate  subexpression is as following:

> The immediate subexpressions of an expression e are
>
> > 1. the constituent expressions of e's operands
> > 2. **any function call that e implicitly invokes**,
> > 3. if e is a lambda-expression, the initialization of the entities captured by copy and the constituent expressions of the initializer of the init-captures,
> > 4. if e is a function call or implicitly invokes a function, **the constituent expressions of each default argument** used in the call, or
> > 5. if e creates an aggregate object, the constituent expressions of each default member initializer ([class.mem]) used in the initialization.

> A subexpression of an expression e is an immediate subexpression of e or a subexpression of an immediate subexpression of e.

The easy way to understand the rule for subexpression is that it works recursively, that is,

`immediate subexpression of immediate subexpression... of immediate subexpression of e` is a subexpression of `e`.

I agree the expression `throw Y()` is a subexpression of function `B(B&&, int = (throw Y(), 0)) noexcept` due to the fourth bullet.  However, I don't know whether `B(B&&, int = (throw Y(), 0)) noexcept` is considered as an **implicitly invoked function** which is invoked by expression `D​::​D(D&&)`, which seems to obey the second bullet.  if it is that, please consider the following code:

```cpp
class Test{
  Test(){}
  ~Test(){}
};
void func(){
  Test t{} // implicitly invoke the defautl constructor of `Test`
  // would implicitly  invoke the destructor of `Test`
}
int main(){
  func();
}
```

So, as I write in the comment, Is the constructor and the destructor of `Test` is considered as subexpressions of expression `func()`? If it's not, how to interpret the wording `a subexpression of such an initialization`? So, my questions are:

#### Q1:

In the second example, Is the implicitly invoked constructor or destructor be considered as a subexpression of expression `func()`?

#### Q2:

If the answer to the first question is no, then how to interpret `a subexpression of such an initialization`?

Comment: AFAIU, in your second example you don't `implicitly` call the constructor of  `test`, you have literally ask for the creation of the object. In other hand, when you (or the compilator) define `D​::​D(D&&)` even if you just do `D​::​D(D&&){}` it will **implicitly** call the constructor of the base. I think that the difference here

Comment: @MartinMorterol In my second example, I just define an object of type `Test`, I neither explicitly call the constructor for it or call the destructor for it. IIUC, the implicitly invocation means that there's no corresponding function call where the postfix-expression is the function name.

Comment: "I neither explicitly call the constructor", well I disagree (and I might be wrong), for me `Test t{};` is defining and initializing `t` by calling the constructor. To enforce my point, if we define `explicit Test(){}` the second example still compile.

Comment: @MartinMorterol Notice `Test t{};`, I didn't call constructor explicitly for `t`. For `Test t{}` where `{}` is an initializer, namely `braced-list-init`. That's irrelevant to define the constructor as `explicit Test(){}`, the code is still well-formed. because the initialization is direct-list-initialization. Instead, `Test t = {};` would be ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

In [except.spec]/7.2, specifically the wording "a subexpression of such an initialization", what is "such an initialization"? The answer is that it must refer to an initialization described in p7.1:

> a constructor selected by overload resolution in the implicit definition of the constructor for class `X` **to initialize** a potentially constructed subobject, or

It doesn't refer to the initialization of `X`. The text at the beginning of [except.spec]/7 only refers to a "constructor" of `X`, not the "initialization" of `X`. The natural way to read p7.2 is that "such an initialization" refers to the only preceding mention of initialization, which is in p7.1.

So the issue here, in applying [except.spec]/7.2, is not whether the constituent expressions of the default arguments of `B`'s move constructor are subexpressions of the `D` initialization, but rather whether they are subexpressions of the `B` initialization, and the answer is that they are.

Although the above explanation should answer your main question, I will also say that I don't think the constructor of `B` is considered "implicitly invoked" by the constructor of `D` for the purposes of [intro.execution]/10. If it were, then it would mean that the initialization of the `B` subobject is a subexpression of the initialization of `D`. Instead, I believe we should consider the initialization of the `B` subobject as a full-expression under [intro.execution]/12.3:

> A *full-expression* is [...] an *init-declarator* (Clause 11) or a *mem-initializer* (15.6.2), including the constituent expressions of the
> initializer, [...]

Although the wording is not clear on this, I believe the initialization of the `B` subobject is considered to be done by a *mem-initializer* for the purposes of [intro.execution]. [class.copy.ctor]/14, which defines the behaviour of a defaulted move constructor, does not explicitly say that bases and members are initialized as if by a *mem-initializer*. However, it would be strange if a defaulted definition of a move constructor had a different subexpression hierarchy from the corresponding user-defined constructor.

If we treat the implicit call to the base class constructor as not being a *mem-initializer*, but rather a "function call that `e` implicitly invokes" under [intro.execution]/10.2, it would mean that the former is not a full-expression, and there is no point for destruction of temporaries at the end of it. It would be really strange if this were the case: it would mean temporaries created during the execution of a defaulted move constructor are destroyed at different times than temporaries created during the execution of an equivalent user-provided move constructor. A simple [experiment on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/f4Y4PqhME) reassures me that GCC and Clang do not take such a strange interpretation.

In your second example, the expression `func()` does not implicitly invoke anything. Functions that are invoked in the body of `func()` don't count. The point about implicit invocations includes such things as the destructors of temporaries at the end of a full-expression, constructors called to materialize temporary objects, constructors and conversion operators invoked by implicit conversions required by an expression, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

For the first rule, the selected constructor to initialize base sub-object of type `B` is `B (B&&, int = (throw Y(), 0)) noexcept`, which is declared to have a non-throwing exception specification.  This means that the constructor for `B` will not throw when called.  However, before `D` calls `B`, it must generate the 2nd argument from its default value, which will throw.  Accordingly, `D` will throw not because of `B` but because of the default parameter, which is executed outside `B`.

In order to see what a subexpression of an initialisation is, you need to consider the code generated by the compiler.  Your call of `func()` does not construct an object of type `T` in the scope of the call, in that nothing gets injected into the scope of `main` by the compiler.  The object is constructed in the scope of `func` and that does not count.

Comment: You did not interpret that what is "a subexpression of such an initialization"